# FFmpeg jump to most recent frame

Tags: objective-c, ffmpeg

I am looking for some help with dropping/skipping FFmpeg frames. The project I am working on streams live video which when the app goes into the background, upon returning to an active state the video stream spends a long time catching up by fast forwarding itself to the current frame. This isn't ideal and what I am aiming to achieve is have the app immediately jump to the most recent frame.

What I need to do is drop the amount of frames that are being fast-forwarded in order to catch up to the most recent frame. Is this possible? Here is my current code which decodes the frames:

```
- (NSArray *) decodeFrames: (CGFloat) minDuration
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    @synchronized (lock) {

        if([_reading integerValue] != 1){

            _reading = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

            @synchronized (_seekPosition) {
                if([_seekPosition integerValue] != -1 && _seekPosition){
                    [self seekDecoder:[_seekPosition longLongValue]];
                    _seekPosition = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
                }
            }

            if (_videoStream == -1 &&
                _audioStream == -1)
                return nil;

            AVPacket packet;

            CGFloat decodedDuration = 0;

            CGFloat totalDuration = [TimeHelper calculateTimeDifference];

            do {

                BOOL finished = NO;
                int count = 0;


                while (!finished) {

                    if (av_read_frame(_formatCtx, &packet) < 0) {
                        _isEOF = YES;
                        [self endOfFileReached];
                        break;
                    }

                    [self frameRead];

                    if (packet.stream_index ==_videoStream) {

                        int pktSize = packet.size;

                        while (pktSize > 0) {

                            int gotframe = 0;
                            int len = avcodec_decode_video2(_videoCodecCtx,
                                                            _videoFrame,
                                                            &gotframe,
                                                            &packet);

                            if (len < 0) {
                                LoggerVideo(0, @"decode video error, skip packet");
                                break;
                            }

                            if (gotframe) {


                                    if (!_disableDeinterlacing &&
                                        _videoFrame->interlaced_frame) {

                                        avpicture_deinterlace((AVPicture*)_videoFrame,
                                                              (AVPicture*)_videoFrame,
                                                              _videoCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                                              _videoCodecCtx->width,
                                                              _videoCodecCtx->height);
                                    }

                                    KxVideoFrame *frame = [self handleVideoFrame];
                                    if (frame) {

                                        [result addObject:frame];
                                        _position = frame.position;
                                        decodedDuration += frame.duration;
                                        if (decodedDuration > minDuration)
                                            finished = YES;
                            }



                            } else {
                                count++;
                            }

                            if (0 == len)
                                break;

                            pktSize -= len;
                        }
                    }
                    av_free_packet(&packet);
                }
            } while (totalDuration > 0);
            _reading = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
            return result;
        }

    }

    return result;
```

Comment: Try `av_index_search_timestamp(_videoStream, pts, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD);` with a pts greater than a demuxed or expected current pts. If successful, stream index value (>= 0) will be returned. Then do a avio_seek to the frame with that index entry. Then continue with av_read_frame.